# What's up with position on Scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros

I'm trying to get the original input string of a parameter to a macro, but the returned position seems a bit off. Consider this macro, for example:

```
object M {
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context
  import language.experimental.macros
  def f[T](v: => T) = macro fImpl[T]
  def fImpl[T : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(v: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val pos = v.tree.pos
    println(pos.lineContent)
    println(" " * pos.column + "^")
    println(" " * pos.point + "^")
    c.literalUnit 
  }
}
```

When I try it with this file:

```
object N extends App {
  val x = 1
  val y = 2
  println(M.f(x + y))
}
```

I get this output:

```
  println(M.f(x + y))
                 ^
                                                                  ^
```

which doesn't make sense to me. I'd expect it to point to `x`, or be off by one. What's up with that?

Comment: If you change it to `println(M.f(x.+(y)))` the point shifts over one to point at the y, and with `println(M.f(if (true) {x + y}))` it points at the f in if. I suspect it is trying to point at the top of the tree, the invocation of + or the if, though whether it is supposed to or not is another question. There may be at least one off-by-one error as well. This looks appropriate for a bug report to me.

Comment: It would be funnier if the question read, What's your position on macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an off-by-one bug in the sense that `Position.column` and `Position.line` are 1-based.

It's a documentation bug in the sense that they bothered to document the API but didn't bother to mention that.

You can compile with `-Yrangepos` and:

```
val n = pos.column - (pos.point - pos.startOrPoint) - 1
println(" " * n + "^")
```

or similar to indicate the earliest position in the tree.

```
println(M.f(x + y))
            ^
```

Update:

Letting the macro return the expression it's given, and compiling with `-Xprint:typer -Yshow-trees`, the tree is the inner `Apply` node, which is positioned at the `+`:

```
      Apply( // def println(x: Any): Unit in object Predef, tree.tpe=Unit
        scala.this."Predef"."println" // def println(x: Any): Unit in object Predef, tree.tpe=(x: Any)Unit
        Apply( // def +(x: Int): Int in class Int, tree.tpe=Int
          "x"."$plus" // def +(x: Int): Int in class Int, tree.tpe=(x: Int)Int
          "y" // val y: Int, tree.tpe=Int
        )
      )
```

With a "range" position, the position of the top of the tree includes everything beneath it.  So while `point` is where the `+` is, the `start` of a range position is the earliest position of everything enclosed by the range position, i.e., everything lower in the tree. In this case, the left leaf is the `x`.

So the difference `point - start` tells you how far to back up.

(I haven't considered what if the offsets into the source file are different from column offsets because of differences in character encoding.)

Comment: But _what_ is `column` pointing to? And what's the meaning of `pos.point - pos.startOrPoint` (both of which were kind of meaningless to me)?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I only know enough about range positions to have introduced a bug once which the IDE people had to fix. At least I was also fixing a bug, so it was a wash.  Also, I thought -Yrangepos was going to become the default? Updated with my limited knowledge.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral There are improved comments (and code) at https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2936

Comment: Ah, I finally realized that `point`, `start` and `end` point to offsets into the file, not the line.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral That is a useful realization.